# How to Pass base64 encoded image data from PHP to Android, and do Decoding in Android side and Save

Tags: php, android, base64

Friends i am doing an Android Application where i need to get Image Files from FTP server using PHP. I have successfully decoded image data using base64 encoding with PHP

```
<?php
   $encoded=base64_encode(file_get_contents($server_file));
   echo  $encoded;
?>
```

Android Application is now Able to receive this string also. But the main Problem is that i could't able to recreate the image using Android base64 Decoder.An image is getting created but it is invalid.

```
    String encodedData= result.toString();
    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedData,Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File(sdcard.getAbsolutePath() + "/MyAppDataFolder");
    dir.mkdir();
    File file1 = new File(dir, "sampleImage2.jpg");
    output = new FileOutputStream(file1);
    decodedByte.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,output);
    output.flush();
    os.close();
```

**result** is the Actual result returned by PHP as Encoded String.

Comment: What's `mThumbnail` and why do you pass it to the `decode` method?

Comment: Really sorry i have edited the Code

Comment: So what's the problem?  Errors in logcat?  You haven't told us what goes wrong.

Comment: Not able to recreate the Image. an image is getting created but it is invalid

Comment: Are you sure the encoding is correct?

Comment: Yup encoding is correct. it can be decoded by php side well

Comment: `i need to get Image Files from FTP server using PHP`. Impossible. Nonsense. Php is only available for http.

Comment: `I have successfully decoded image data using base64 encoding with PHP`. No. In that php script you encoded an image.

Comment: We can not check your android code as you did not show how you retrieved `result`. You did not even tell the type of that variable. So we do know nothing about `result.toString();`. Please post complete code.

Comment: The bad thing about your code is that you use BitmapFactory and Bitmap. Instead you should directly write `byte[] decodedString` to file.

Comment: @greenapps: Yes, please tell me how can i pass the image data to android using php

Comment: You are already doing that. So it is unclear what you ask. Further you should have reacted on what i said.

Comment: @greenapps byte[] decodedString will work ??

Comment: What do you mean with 'will work'?